# Asking multiplication questions and computing the total of answers correct in Java

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop, do-while

The code should output a table for Farenheit and Celsius

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Fahrenheit\tCelsius");
    System.out.println("=======================");
     for(int temp = -45; temp <= 120; temp += 5) //for(int i = 0; i <= 100; i+= 10)
        {
            System.out.printf("%5d       |",          temp);
            double sum = (temp + (9.0/5.0)) * 32;   
            System.out.printf("%5d", (int)sum );
            System.out.printl

n();
```

Comment: One major issue: don't keep re-creating the Scanner within the while loop. You're basing the Scanner on System.in, and you don't want it to end until the program is completely done and no longer needs this input. Thus make the Scanner once and once only **before** your while loop.

Comment: Do I have a deja vulnerable? Didn't I the almost same question the other day? Did it happen to get closed and deleted and now you try again?

Comment: Thanks for answering. I do have that tendency. I will see if I can modify.  @ Hovercraft.

Comment: I don't know what you are talking about and I am just trying to learn/understand. If you don't want to help that is fine. @ GhostCat

Answer (score 0):

You should do this all in one encompassing while loop.

the while loop pseudo code is like this:

```
string answer = "";
While (answer != quit)
{
answer = (ask question to user)
if (answer != quit)
   compute/display response
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your braces are not opened and closed properly. Also the userScore and totalScore is reset in each iteration. So you will not have the proper score. Move it outside the loop.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Multiplication {

    private static String question;
    private static Scanner input;
    private static Scanner scanner;
    private static int totalScore;
    private static int answer1;
    private static int userScore;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int number1;
        int number2;
        totalScore = 0;
        userScore = 0;
        input = new Scanner(System.in);
        do {
            number1 = (int)(Math.random() * 10);
            number2 = (int)(Math.random() * 10);    

            System.out.print("What is " + number1 + " * " + number2 + "? ");
            int answer = input.nextInt();
            while (number1 * number2 != answer) 
            {
                int answer1 = number1 * number2;
                System.out.println("Incorrect. The answer is " + answer1+".");
                System.out.print("Want more questions yes or no? ");
                scanner = new Scanner (System.in);
                question = scanner.next();
                totalScore++;
                break;
            } 

            if (number1 * number2 == answer)
            { 
                System.out.println("Correct. Nice work!");
                System.out.print("Want more questions yes or no? ");
                scanner = new Scanner (System.in);
                question = scanner.next(); 
                userScore++;
                totalScore++;
            }

        }while(question.equals("yes") || question.equals("y"));
        System.out.println("You have this many questions correct:" + userScore +" out of " + totalScore);
    }
}
```

**A Better Implementation**

The code looks more readable here and few unnecessary lines of code are removed.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Multiplication {

    private static final Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);
    private static int totalScore = 0;
    private static int userScore = 0;
    private static int number1;
    private static int number2;
    private static int answer;

    public static boolean continueExe(){
        String question;
        System.out.print("Want more questions yes or no? ");
        question = scanner.next();
        return (question.equals("yes") || question.equals("y"));        
    }

    public static void printOutput(){
        System.out.println("You have this many questions correct:" + userScore +" out of " + totalScore);
    }

    public static void askQuestion(){
        number1 = (int)(Math.random() * 10);
        number2 = (int)(Math.random() * 10);
        System.out.print("What is " + number1 + " * " + number2 + "? ");
    }

    public static void readAnswer(){
        answer = scanner.nextInt();
    }

    public static void isAnswerCorrect(){
        if (number1 * number2 != answer){
            System.out.println("Incorrect. The answer is " + number1 * number2 +".");
        }else{
            userScore++;
            System.out.println("Correct. Nice work!");
        }
        totalScore++;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        do{
            askQuestion();
            readAnswer();
            isAnswerCorrect();
        }while(continueExe());
        printOutput();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. The second code looks really advanced.

Answer (score 0):

Mistake was you opened '{' two times for 'if'statement -

```
if (question.equals("no")||question.equals("n")&& (number1 * number2 == answer)){ 
{
```

and forgot to close one bracket in last line.

Below code solves error due to brackets:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Program3_3 {

private static String question;
private static Scanner input;
private static Scanner scanner;
private static int totalScore;
private static int answer1;
private static int userScore;

public static void main(String[] args) {
do {
    int number1 = (int)(Math.random() * 10);
    int number2 = (int)(Math.random() * 10);    
    totalScore = 0;
    userScore = 0;
    input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("What is " + number1 + " * " + number2 + "? ");
    int answer = input.nextInt();
    while (number1 * number2 != answer) {
        int answer1 = number1 * number2;
        System.out.println("Incorrect. The answer is " + answer1+".");
        System.out.print("Want more questions yes or no? ");
        scanner = new Scanner (System.in);
        question = scanner.next(); 
        break;
     } 

    if (number1 * number2 == answer){ 
        System.out.println("Correct. Nice work!");
        System.out.print("Want more questions yes or no? ");
        scanner = new Scanner (System.in);
        question = scanner.next(); 
        }
    if (question.equals("no")||question.equals("n")&& (number1 * number2 == answer))
    {
        userScore++;
        totalScore++;
          System.out.println("You have this many questions correct:" + totalScore);
       }
} 
   while(question.equals("yes") || question.equals("y"));
    }
 }
```